# How to add product on homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, category

Magento 1.9.0.1

Created category home

Added to homepage:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Following happened:

Added 4 products from category 1 to category home - working fine

Added 6 products from category 2 to category home - working fine

Removed 4 products from category 1 from category home - no products on homepage - category 1 shows only the 4 products that used to be on homepage, not all 105 products - category 2 shows all products but not the 6 that suppose to be on home page

Answer (score 1):

If the amount of products in the category and on your site are not the same this is usually one of few things.

1. `Refresh Cache. via system->cache management`
2. `Reindex via system->index management`
3. `or your products are not in stock and magento configures default that out of stock products don't get shown.`

hope this helps you!